# Is it possible to show Alert or View when rewarded ad is finished? (above rewarded ad)

Tags: react-native, admob

I'm trying to add to my react-native app ad.
I'm using `@react-native-firebase/admob` package.

And my question is: when the user is finished watching a rewarded ad is it possible to show Alert (android) or customized View above this finished rewarding ad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it is possible, but you should NOT do this because it is violation of AdMob policy.

AdMob will stop serving ads in your app and Google Play could reject your app.

[AdMob Policy](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10437795?hl=en-GB)

> **Content obscuring Google-served ads**
> We do not allow content that:
>
> fully or partially obscures Google-served ads.

> Publishers should avoid site layouts in which the content fully or partially obscures Google ads. These layouts make it hard for users to distinguish between the content and ads.

Also check out AdMob [Policies for ads that offer rewards](http://%20%20https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578?hl=en&ref_topic=7384517)